# getAssets NullPointerException XML from Assets

Tags: android, xml-parsing, nullpointerexception

Before I ask my question I'll point out I am brand new to android programming.
So, I'm trying to parse data from an xml file in my assets folder and place the data in a custom listview. I've been looking around for how to parse the files correctly and how to not get the NullPointerException for a few days now. If the real problem here is that my attempted to code is just terrible that's a possible solution. Any help with any part of my incompetence would be greatly appreciated.
Code:

```
 public class Z_PullMain extends ListActivity {

AssetManager manager = getAssets();

private ListView lv;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_specials_weekday_list);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Context context=getApplicationContext();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listofspec = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String lowercaseday = ((GlobalVariables) getApplication()).getlowercaseday();
    HashMap<String, String> specmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("bar2.xml");
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(stream, "UTF-8");

    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
     if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
         String tag_name=xpp.getName();
        if (tag_name==lowercaseday);{
            eventType = xpp.next();
            specmap.put("name", xpp.nextText().toString());
            xpp.next();
            specmap.put("price", xpp.nextText().toString());
            xpp.next();
            specmap.put("start", xpp.nextText().toString());
            xpp.next();
            specmap.put("end", xpp.nextText().toString());
            xpp.next();
            listofspec.add(specmap);
        }
     }
     eventType = xpp.next();
    }
    System.out.println("End document");
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            listofspec,
            R.layout.custom_row_view,
            new String[] {"name", "price", "start", "end"},
            new int[] {R.id.name,R.id.price, R.id.start, R.id.end}
            );
      setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <thursday>
        <name>Everything</name>
        <price>1/2 Price</price>
        <start>10:00 PM</start>
        <end>12:00 AM</end>
    </thursday>
    <thursday>
        <name>Cover</name>
        <price>Free</price>
        <start>3:00 PM</start>
        <end>10:00 PM</end>
    </thursday>
    <friday>
        <name>Everything</name>
        <price>1/2 Price</price>
        <start>7:00 PM</start>
        <end>9:00 PM</end>
    </friday>
    <friday>
        <name>Coors Light Drafts</name>
        <price>$1.00</price>
        <start>3:00 PM</start>
        <end>12:00 AM</end>
    </friday>
    <saturday>
        <name>Everything</name>
        <price>1/2 Price</price>
        <start>7:00 PM</start>
        <end>9:00 PM</end>
    </saturday>
    <saturday>
        <name>Pinnacle</name>
        <price>$3.00</price>
        <start>3:00 PM</start>
        <end>12:00 AM</end>
    </saturday>
</root>
```

LogCat:

```
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.tronapps.barspecials/com.tronapps.barspecials.Z_PullMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:83)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at com.tronapps.barspecials.Z_PullMain.<init>(Z_PullMain.java:22)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-31 17:22:21.380: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     ... 11 more
07-31 17:23:14.881: E/Trace(2743): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

EDIT-------
The nullpointer exception is fixed, but the list is empty. This is the new logcat

```
07-31 18:20:22.221: W/System.err(3145): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: precondition: START_TAG (position:TEXT (whitespace)@3:2 in java.io.InputStreamReader@410b6a48) 
07-31 18:20:22.221: W/System.err(3145):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextText(KXmlParser.java:2053)
07-31 18:20:22.231: W/System.err(3145):     at com.tronapps.barspecials.Z_PullMain.onCreate(Z_PullMain.java:49)
07-31 18:20:22.231: W/System.err(3145):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-31 18:20:22.231: W/System.err(3145):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-31 18:20:22.241: W/System.err(3145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-31 18:20:22.241: W/System.err(3145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-31 18:20:22.241: W/System.err(3145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-31 18:20:22.251: W/System.err(3145):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-31 18:20:22.251: W/System.err(3145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 18:20:22.251: W/System.err(3145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 18:20:22.251: W/System.err(3145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-31 18:20:22.263: W/System.err(3145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 18:20:22.271: W/System.err(3145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 18:20:22.282: W/System.err(3145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-31 18:20:22.282: W/System.err(3145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-31 18:20:22.282: W/System.err(3145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try to initialize AssetManager object inside onCeate method as `manager = getAssets();`

Comment: so now I have  
        manager = getAssets();  
        try {
         InputStream stream;
         stream = manager.open("bar2.xml");
which still resulted in the same error as before.

Comment: means working or still getting same issue?

Comment: Also make sure you've changed `AssetManager manager = getAssets();` at the top to just `AssetManager manager;` Apologies if this is obvious.

Comment: changing the 'AssetManager' at the top fixed the NullPointerException now my list is empty, however so I'm getting to work on that, if anyone has any other "obvious" points that I'm to stupid to see I would greatly aprreciate it.

Comment: @Nizam line 22 of my java file is the blank line between AssetManager and Listview

Answer (score 0):

Please add your Activity `Z_PullMain` in your AndroidManifest.xml.

When you want to making new activity, you should register it in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: That was my first thought so I put it in my manifest already.

Answer (score 0):

"Also make sure you've changed `AssetManager manager = getAssets();` at the top to just `AssetManager manager;` Apologies if this is obvious" - @Ken Wolf solved my NullPointer problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by using

```
context.getAssets();
```

or, in your case:

```
this.getAssets();
```